# Should Copy Paste be allowed in Confirm e-mail address field?

Tags: manual-testing

Should Copy Paste be allowed in Confirm e-mail address field?
What if we type in incorrect email address. And we are copy pasting the same? And this email id is not used for any sign up process and is used as a part of filing any insurance claim. It can cause issues if mails are not delivered. Personally i don't like to have copy paste feature in Confirm email address field. But i would like to know the common practice. Should it be allowed or not?

Comment: IMHO opinon-based. Do whatever makes sense. How much hassle it is if incorrect email is entered? How hard is to fix it? How user can recover?

Comment: @peter Once its entered its done.There is no option to correct it from the front end.I don't have idea about the back end. I am a test engineer and don't know about the back end details.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software requirements, not testing.

Comment: @user246 Iam testing an application. In that these fields are there.I can add my suggestions to that. In my opinion i would like to disable copy paste in Confirm field. i wanted to know whether it is a common practice or not to disable confirm field

Comment: @sree, you're better off having a look at somewhere like ux.stackexchange.com to see if it's a common practice. I'd agree with user246, this is more about the domain expectations than testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should Copy Paste be allowed in Confirm e-mail address field?

Is this mentioned in your application's requirements?

Personally, I think forcing the user to enter the same information twice is foolish. IMHO, it's far better to have a 2-stage confirmation where the user must respond to an email before registration/confirmation is complete. If the user entered an incorrect email, the 2nd stage will fail and the user will know about it.

But if your requirements are such that a "confirm email" field is required, I think it makes sense to disable the ability to paste into that field. That's an individual preference - the standards in your shop may differ.

> What if we type in incorrect email address. And we are copy pasting
>   the same?

Yes.

Comment: Its not there in app requirements. Actually the scenario is related to call center type, where some one from a company will make a call and the one who is attending the call will collect the details from them. So what happens is he will collect the email address from the caller and will enter that in the email address field and in the conformation field he has to enter by himself, no need to ask the caller again.

Comment: Assuming the call takers are experienced at using the system, it seems odd to me to force them to enter the customer's email twice. I wouldn't design it that way. But if the field is there, I would probably disable the past feature.

Comment: Might also want to have email validation as well.  Make sure it has the @ sign and a valid domain as well.  Personally I find it more annoying to type it twice and often mess up on the second one and then it clears both forcing me to type it 4 times.  Copy paste saves time and if they type it wrong and copy it wrong that's kind of a user error that can't be fixed...better to do the email verification as mentioned above.

Comment: Ultimate decision point: "Is this mentioned in your application's requirements?" +1

Comment: "If the user entered an incorrect email, the 2nd stage will fail and the user will know about it." I would dispute this: the user would *assume* that they entered the right email address, and will have no way (short of expert-level insight into browsers) to verify that they submitted the right address. They will therefore **assume that your service is broken.**

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I think if a user circumvents a quality feature and therefore the application don't work as required, it's in his responsibility. But my opinion doesn't matter.

The question is offtopic (here), since it's about requirements. If you are to give feedback, ask exactly this question to the requirements engineer. If he doesn't know he'll have to ask the stakeholders.

It doesn't matter what our opinion is. Your feedback in this case can be to ask the right question, not neccessarily to make a suggestion.